# How to create my own library on CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp and I managed to work my way out doing some great stuff with this powerful framewoek. Seeking some organization in my code, I am looking for a way to create some kind of  side library to call it whenever it.

I am working on the mailing layer of my application using the built in mailing utility, so I want to know how to create a library where i can store my functions.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the problem with using /Lib folder and your own lib classes like we all do? See [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/tree/master/Lib) for example. You learn a lot from looking at other peoples code and plugins and how they du things. In your case you could very well create a plugin that contains everything -so it can easily be shared across apps.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about making a plug-in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can create your own library file in

> /app/Lib/Library_Class_name.php

```
class Library_Class_name {
   public function function_name() {

   }
}
```

after this you should need to use load this Library file to your application  use below code

> App::uses('Library_Class_name', 'Lib');

One this, If you want to load this file for entire application you need to use above App::uses code to your Config/bootstrap.php file otherwise you can use this to needed files or functions.